# Pumping machine (Centrifugal ) fails to pump

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, pressure, pumps

I have a centrifugal pumping machine that fails to pump up consistently. When powdered on, it spills up water, then stops and continues intermittently like that without a consistent flow of water out. What could be the cause? I just rewound it, and it works just fine. I suspected the capacitor, but not fully. Anyone who has more understanding should please tell me what's wrong. Thanks in advance[image: This like the pumping machine]

Comment: Is the supply of water restricted?

Comment: If it is fine after rewinding, the problem was probably with the winding or the brushes.

Comment: @AJN could it be the capacitor because it uses a run capacitor?

Comment: Does the motor stop or does the water output stop ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 the motor doesn't stop but makes like hum hum hum sound. It seems like it on and off rapidly. I believe this causes the water to not flow out as normal but intermittently.

Comment: Does the motor stop or does the water flow stop while the motor continues turning?

Comment: When switched on, water rushes up and stop then continues like that. No continuous flow and the motor works.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check the *inlet* (suction side) of the pump for leaks. If there is a vacuum leak in the inlet plumbing, it will suck air into the pump housing and cause the pumping action to stop.

Comment: I don't think there is air leakage. Its air tight.

Answer (score 0):

You may have check the seals in housing, otherwise the pump is sucking air instead of water. Run thru a trial test in a tub/pool